# how can I sort a list including vectors?

Tags: julia

I have list including some points in two dimensions.
for example

```
List=[270 180 -180;-570 -510 -67.5]
```

I want sort it by element one

```
List=[-180 180 270;-67.5 -510 -570]
```

when I use sort function the code gives me this list

```
-180.0   180.0  270.0
-570.0  -510.0  -67.5
```

How can I achieve that list.

Please help me. Thanks for your kindly helps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of using `indexin` to "reverse search" each sorted element, as user172056 proposes, I would recommend building a sorting permutation  for the first row and indexing with that:

```
julia> l[:, sortperm(view(l, 1, :))]
2×3 Array{Float64,2}:
 -180.0   180.0   270.0
  -67.5  -510.0  -570.0
```

If you also plan to sort by the second row later, it might also be necessary to specify a stable sorting algorithm ([`sortperm`](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1.0/base/sort/#Base.sortperm) by default seems to use an unstable one):

```
julia> l[:, sortperm(view(l, 1, :), alg = Base.Sort.DEFAULT_STABLE)]
2×3 Array{Float64,2}:
 -180.0   180.0   270.0
  -67.5  -510.0  -570.0
```

Answer (score 0):

So you have an object `List`which is in fact an 2D array with 2 rows and multiple columns I presume. Each column represents a pair of coordinates and you want a sorted `List` based on for example the sorted first row of coordinates. I would do it like this:

```
SortRow=List[1,:]
3-element Array{Float64,1}:
270.0
180.0
-180.0
```

Sort this element, obtain the indices with `indexin` built-in function:

```
IndexRow=indexin(sort(SortRow),SortRow)
3-element Array{Union{Nothing, Int64},1}:
3
2
1
```

Now reconstruct the `List` object:

```
SortedPoints = List[:,IndexRow]
2×3 Array{Float64,2}:
-180.0   180.0   270.0
-67.5  -510.0  -570.0
```